# YAML does not call the constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I've tried following the instructions [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers), which led me to this code:

```
import yaml
class Step(yaml.YAMLObject):

    yaml_tag = "!step"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception("Intentionally.")

yaml.load("""
--- !step
    foo: bar
    ham: 42
""")
```

Expected behaviour: I get an exception. But what I observe is, that my YAML markup results in a `Step` instance and I'm able to work with it, access methods, attributes (like `foo` in the code above) and so on. Reading the documentation, I cannot find my mistake since it suggests that the constructor is called with all the key-value-pairs as keyword arguments.

Basically the example in the doc works, but not because of the constructor's implementation, but because of the fact that the key-value-pairs (properties of the `Monster`) are used to fill the object's dict.

Anyone here knows about that?

I'm working with python3 but did a quick evaluation in python2 and observed the same.

*edit*

What I wanted to do: To stay in the linked example (documentation), if the `Monster`s `name` starts with a `B`, double the value of `ac`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> yaml.YAMLObject uses metaclass magic to register a constructor, which transforms a YAML node to a class instance, and a representer, which serializes a class instance to a YAML node.

Internally, the default `constructor` registered by `yaml.YAMLObject` will call `YourClass.__new__` then set the fields on your class by using `instance.__dict__`. See [this method](http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/trunk/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L401) for more detail.

Depending on what you want to do, you could either put some logic in `Step.__new__` (but you won't be getting any of the fields in `**kwargs`, or [register a custom constructor](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Constructorsrepresentersresolvers).

Comment: So the example in the documentation may be outdated? Because the constructor they show might not be neccessary then: It's not called and what is done there, basically adding all the ``kwargs`` as properties, is done anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding. I don't know if this assumption holds true, but I think

```
load, dump = yaml.load, yaml.dump
foo = "any valid yaml string"

load(foo) == load(dump(load(foo))) # should be true
```

If I now do what I suggested in the question, really changing a property while loading, would change this "equation" and result in a behaviour I most likely don't want.